# In Emacs, How to replace only on matching lines

Tags: emacs, elisp

For example: In VIM,

```
test
sample replace
test1
replace
sample test2
```

:g/sample/s/replace/test3/ - will replace "replace" only on matching lines with "sample"

```
test
sample test3
test1
replace
sample test2
```

In VIM, to replace only on non-matching lines can be done by 
:v/sample/s/replace/test3 - will replace "replace" only on non-matching lines which does not contain "sample"

```
test
sample replace
test1
test3
sample test2
```

How can above thing can be accomplished using emacs?

Answer (score 18):

Are you using Emacs 24 perchance? If so, you can use the built-in occur-edit-mode:

- First use one of the occur functions to obtain a buffer of lines matching your pattern:
  <kbd>M-x</kbd> `occur` <kbd>RET</kbd> (pattern) <kbd>RET</kbd>
- Now press <kbd>e</kbd> to enter occur-edit-mode to perform interactive edits on those lines only.
- Search and replace.
- Finally, <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> to exit occur-edit-mode, and <kbd>q</kbd> to dismiss the occur buffer.

There are third-party libraries to perform similar tricks on earlier versions of Emacs. I believe `moccur-edit` is one of them, but I've never used it.

edit: Regarding the second part of your question, while I'm not familiar with a more direct way of accomplishing that, we can hack this same method to achieve it:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `occur` <kbd>RET</kbd> `.` <kbd>RET</kbd> to obtain occur buffer containing *all* lines
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd> to make occur buffer writable
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `flush-lines` <kbd>RET</kbd> (pattern) <kbd>RET</kbd> to delete matching lines
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd> to make occur buffer read-only again
- <kbd>e</kbd> to invoke occur-edit-mode (and then continue as before...)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything built in, but some elisp can do it:

```lisp
(defun my-replace-on-matching-lines (&optional arg)
  "Replace text on lines that match a regexp.
With prefix arg, replace on non-matching lines."
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((regexp (concat ".*"
                         (read-from-minibuffer
                          (concat "Replace on lines "
                                  (if arg "not " "")
                                  "matching regexp: "))))
         (replace (read-from-minibuffer "Replace: "))
         (with (read-from-minibuffer (concat "Replace " replace " with: ")))
         match)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (not (eobp))
        (setq match (looking-at regexp))
        (when (if arg (not match) match)
          (while (search-forward replace (point-at-eol) t)
            (replace-match with nil t)))
        (forward-line)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) [search](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) and [replace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search-And-Replace).

The main idea behind **Icicles** search is to first define *search* ***contexts*** and then search within those contexts using patterns such as substrings and regexps.  And you can just as easily search the [***non***-contexts](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview#SearchOutsideContexts) (text outside the contexts) as the contexts, which addresses your second question.

In this case, the search contexts are the lines that contain `sample`.  This regexp defines the contexts: `.*sample.*`, since `.` matches any character except newline.

For this search you do not want to replace the entire search context, so you would set option `icicle-search-replace-whole-candidate-flag` to nil. It is non-nil by default --- you just need to hit <kbd>M-_</kbd> (once) to toggle it. This makes whatever matches your current minibuffer input be the text that is replaced, as opposed to making the entire context be what is replaced).

You can visit any of the contexts (the lines containing `sample`) you want, in any order.  You can cycle among some or all of them if you like.  You can even sort the contexts in various ways, for easy comparison or to change the cycling order.  (Sorting does not change your text in any way --- the contexts are sorted in buffer `*Completions*`.)

But here you're really interested in those contexts that contain `replace`, so you type `replace` in the minibuffer.  Only those contexts remain as candidates.  If you change your minibuffer input, the set of search hits --- the matching contexts --- changes dynamically.  Again, you can visit any of the matching contexts in any order, cycle among them, etc.

Here are the steps:

1. <kbd>C-`</kbd>, to initiate Icicles search.
2. You are prompted for a regexp that defines the contexts.  You type `.*sample.*`, then hit <kbd>RET</kbd>.
3. You hit <kbd>S-TAB</kbd> to see the contexts highlighted in your file and listed in buffer `*Completions*`.  The search contexts are *completion candidates*.
4. You type `replace` to narrow the contexts to those that contain `replace`.
5. You hit <kbd>M-_</kbd> (Meta underscore) to toggle whole-context replacement OFF (assuming it is currently ON, which it is by default).
6. You hit <kbd>C-down</kbd> (Control down arrow) to move to the first matching context.
7. You hit <kbd>S-RET</kbd> to replace the part of the context that your current input (`replace`) matches.
8. Since you have not yet defined a replacement you are prompted for it.  You type `test3`.
9. That replaces the first occurrence of `replace`.  You hit <kbd>S-RET</kbd> again to replace the next, and again to replace the next, etc.

Note that this lets you replace multiple occurrences of `replace` in the same context, one after another.

If you know that you want to replace *all* occurrences of `replace`, at step 9 you can just hit <kbd>M-|</kbd> to do that.

Replacement is only *on demand*.  You are essentially just searching. You decide which search hits to visit.  In the example I gave, you cycled among the search hits using `C-down`, but you could just as easily have visited only certain hits.

And when you visit a search hit, you decide whether to carry out a replacement there.  You are not queried for each hit in turn and forced to answer `y` or `n` etc., as in `query-replace`.

(If there is only one search context after filtering, e.g., only one line with both `sample` and `replace`, then you are taken to that context immediately, instead of being given a chance to replace parts of it.)

To search the *non*-contexts instead of the contexts --- that is, text that is outside a line containing `sample`, hit <kbd>C-M-~</kbd> once during completion in a search, to toggle searching inside/outside contexts.  (The toggle takes effect starting with the next search, not the one where you hit <kbd>C-M-~</kbd>.)

(An alternative approach, with some differences, is to `grep` for the lines containing `sample`,
then hit <kbd>C-`</kbd> in the `*grep*` buffer, then proceed as above --- IOW, use `grep` to define the search contexts.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regluar expression search/replace thus:

```
M-x query-replace-regexp   (or C-M-%)
\(sample.*\)replace      RET
\1test3
```

This will replace `replace` for `test3` on all lines with `sample` preceding `replace`.

It is not exactly what you requested (where `sample` can be anywhere on the line).

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-regexp` (or `query-replace-regexp`)
- Pattern to match: `replace\(.*sample.*\)\|\(sample.*?\)replace\(.*\)`
- Replacement text: `\2test3\1\3`

This approach only handles the first part of the question.  The second part would probably require some Lisp code to be written, since Emacs regexps don't include lookahead assertions.

Answer (score -1):

The most obvious answer to this question has been absent thus far...

### evil-mode

If you use `evil-mode`, you can use the same `:g` (`:global`) and `:v` (`:vglobal`) ex commands in Emacs.

```
:g/sample/s/replace/test3
:v/sample/s/replace/test3
```

**warning:** Do *not* end the command in a slash, or it will break the behaviour of these commands. A slash followed by one or more flags is fine.

Comment: Downvoter: if you think there's something wrong with this answer, please explain in a comment.